# Blender as Python Module is not able to compile and not able to get bin\bpy.pyd

Tags: python

I am using window 10 64 bit, python version 3.6.3, TortoiseSVN  , cmake for windows and  visual studio 2015 community version for building blender as python module

I followed various Articles for building blender & blender as python module

1. Reference from official site for building blender https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows
2. Reference from official site for building and using blender as python module https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule
3. I readed various articles and forum comments on it. Few best i thought are http://cobertos.com/compiling-blender-as-a-python-module-for-windows-10-x64/

Using official Tutorial (link 1 mention above) for compiling blender in windows , i am able to generate .sln file using make full command but when I'm building by right clicking on install in solution explorer in visual studio 2015, I'm getting so many errors like:

```
Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  132
```

and numerous others. I tried using CMake Gui, but that also gives errors when I click on Configure.

---

similarly when i building blender as python module , on typing

`cmake -DWITH_PLAYER=OFF -DWITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF -DWITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON -DPYTHON_VERSION=3.6.3 ../blender    -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64"`

On typing above command with  -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64" I am getting error as

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 to target Windows 10.0.15063.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:111 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    The system cannot find the file specified



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/blender-git/New1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

for these error i tried  running same command form visual studio developer command prompt and using msbuilt but still i get some error message in it.

On typing above command without  -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64"

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 to target Windows 10.0.15063.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_SSE_BUILD
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_SSE_BUILD - Success
-- SSE Support: detected.
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_SSE2_BUILD
-- Performing Test SUPPORT_SSE2_BUILD - Success
-- SSE2 Support: detected.
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.14.1.windows.1")
-- Looking for C++ include memory
-- Looking for C++ include memory - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR_IN_STD_NAMESPACE
-- Performing Test HAVE_SHARED_PTR_IN_STD_NAMESPACE - Success
-- Found shared_ptr in std namespace using <memory> header.
-- Looking for C++ include unordered_map
-- Looking for C++ include unordered_map - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_UNORDERED_MAP_IN_STD_NAMESPACE
-- Performing Test HAVE_UNORDERED_MAP_IN_STD_NAMESPACE - Success
-- Found unordered_map/set in std namespace.
-- 32 bit compiler detected.
-- Visual Studio 2015 detected.
CMake Error at build_files/cmake/platform/platform_win32.cmake:165 (message):
  Windows requires pre-compiled libs at:
  'C:/blender-git/New1/blender/../lib/windows_vc14'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:874 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/blender-git/New1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

and the CMakeOutput.log file contain the text "The system is: Windows - 10.0.15063 - AMD64"

I have gone through various forum and article and not able to help, therefore please help in solving this problem as many of other also facing the same problem.

Comment: So what is in `C:/blender-git/New1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`? There is a reason that CMake tells you to "See also" that file.

Comment: it has content like this : The system is: Windows - 10.0.15063 - AMD64

Comment: Just include the file in your question

Comment: the file contain "The system is: Windows - 10.0.15063 - AMD64" message ,, also mentioned in the question

Comment: Please be precise. "The file contains X" is quite a different statement than "The only thing in the file is X".

Comment: Have you "svn checked out" the [precompiled 64 bit libraries?](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows/svn)

Comment: yes i  tired with this command ( svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/lib/win64_vc14  lib/win64_vc14) and command run as expected wth downloading contant about more then 6 GB in lib folder.